# Facing issue while getting response of API in Powershell

Tags: powershell, api, response

I trying to create a Powershell Script to check that my API's are working or not. I am able to hit the API using Invoke-RestMethod without any issue but I am unable to get API response.

I have tried Invoke-RestMethod and Invoke-WebRequest

```
$user = 'User'
$pass = 'Test123'

$pair = "$($user):$($pass)"

$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))

$basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"

$Headers = @{
    Authorization = $basicAuthValue
}
$url="MYAPIURL"

$person = @{
    UserID='test'
    Password='Test123'
}
$json = $person | ConvertTo-Json


$Result =Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $Headers  -Body $json -Method Post -ContentType 'application/json'

Write-Host ($Result | Format-Table | Out-String)
```

Always getting blank in `$Result`. In Postman it's working fine.

Comment: `$Headers` is undefined, append `-ErrorAction Stop` to `Invoke-RestMethod`.

Comment: Getting blank even after adding -ErrorAction Stop